# How do I tell ninject 3 to use singleton scope by default for all types?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I want my application to always use services as singletons, how do I set up Ninject to use singleton scope by default. I am using conventions to register my types, do I need to use the Bind<> method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hy,
Assuming all your services inherit from `IService` you can write the following

Add the following using statement

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
```

Use the conventions like

```
kernel.Bind( x => x
.FromThisAssembly()
.SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IService>()
.BindAllInterfaces()
.Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));
```

You might need to tweek it a little bit to your needs.

Comment: The 3.0.1.10 version does not have Bind method with this signature.

Comment: @Alexanderius, that's a Ninject.Extensions.Conventions extension.